How to expand the number of data records under the minimum unit of timestamp in Apache IoTDB?
When using Apache IoTDB, I found that under the same TIMESERIES unit, if the time inserted for the data is the same, the data of the later one will overwrite the previous data. The current minimum granularity of time is milliseconds. Does this mean that under the same TIMESERIES, a maximum of 1000 records are allowed in one second? If our scenario may meet more overwriting situation, what do we need to change our usage methods?

You can change the time precision under conf/iotdb-common.properties directory in Apache IoTDB to expand the number or time series "records" you mentioned stored under the same second unit. The parameter timestamp_precision can be set to us or ns.
